# Firebase Functions: Failed to determine service account on using enqueue() function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have this simple `enqueue` method that should add item to my Firebase Functions queue:

```
async enqueue(args: UpdateCounterArgs): Promise<void> {
    const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue("updateCounter");
    await queue.enqueue(args);
  }
```

I also initialize my app with `initializeApp()` - so far I use 2 Realtime Database hooks and Firebase Storage and it was all working, so lack of `initializeApp()` is not an issue.

However, when I try to execute my `enqueue` function in my other hooks, line `await queue.enqueue(args);` throws:

> Error: Failed to determine service account. Initialize the SDK with service account credentials or set service account ID as an app option.

What I tried is to assign `var app = initializeApp()` and pass it like `getFunctions(app)` but same error occurs. I currently test it only on localhost on my machine with Firebase Emulator.

What am I missing?

Here is complete example:

```
import { onValueCreated } from "firebase-functions/v2/database";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { logger } from "firebase-functions/v1";
import { getFunctions } from "firebase-admin/functions";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";

initializeApp();

exports.test = onTaskDispatched((args) => {
  logger.log(args.data);
});

exports.sendToTest = onValueCreated("test/{id}", async (event) => {
  const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue("updateCounter");
  await queue.enqueue(event.data);
});
```

Comment: It would help if you show a *complete minimal* example, along with your init code.  We should be able to duplicate the problem using exactly the code and instructions you provide, as the problem might be with something you're not currently showing. The error message is saying there's a problem with your init, so we need to see that.

Comment: @DougStevenson added an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `initializeApp()` with the `serviceAccountId` like this.

```js
initializeApp({
    serviceAccountId: 'my-client-id@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
});
```

You can find your service account id in the Firebase Console in your project settings.

[image]